# How do you use the GATE Twitter part-of-speech tagger as a model in the StanfordCoreNLP code?

Tags: nlp, gate

How do you use the GATE Twitter part-of-speech tagger as a model in the StanfordCoreNLP code?

The models are here: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/twitter-postagger.html . But, the models don't appear to be in the StanfordCoreNLP format.

I tried downloading the model file from Gate, and putting in it my classpath.  The file is found, but is does not have the right header:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
//props.put("pos.model", "gate-EN-twitter-fast.model");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
    Reading POS tagger model from gate-EN-twitter-fast.model ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:558)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:260)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:127)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:123)
at com.rincaro.mapreduce.apps.StanfordCoreNlpDemo.main(StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java:31)

    Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:857)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:755)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:289)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:253)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:88)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:76)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:556)
... 5 more

    Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.readConfig(TaggerConfig.java:746)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:792)
```

Comment: What version of Stanford are you using? The Gate documentation says the model is for `the Stanford tagger v3.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the model from the recent release (2014 April 11 for v3.3.1) and things worked great with this command:

```
./corenlp.sh -file tweets.txt -pos.model gate-EN-twitter.model -ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak always
```

Comment: Yes, we updated the dependency to the latest tagger jar last week and re-trained the models to match.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested against Stanford 3.3.1

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
props.put("pos.model", "gate-EN-twitter.model");
props.put("dcoref.score", true);
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Sample tweet:

> ikr smh he asked fir yo last name so he can add u on fb lololol

Results without gate-EN-twitter.model

```
word: ikr :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: smh :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: asked :: pos: VBD :: ne:O
word: fir :: pos: NNP :: ne:O
word: yo :: pos: NNP :: ne:O
word: last :: pos: JJ :: ne:O
word: name :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: so :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: can :: pos: MD :: ne:O
word: add :: pos: VB :: ne:O
word: u :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: on :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: fb :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: lololol :: pos: NN :: ne:O
```

Results with gate-EN-twitter.model

```
word: ikr :: pos: UH :: ne:O
word: smh :: pos: UH :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: asked :: pos: VBD :: ne:O
word: fir :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: yo :: pos: PRP$ :: ne:O
word: last :: pos: JJ :: ne:O
word: name :: pos: NN :: ne:O
word: so :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: he :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: can :: pos: MD :: ne:O
word: add :: pos: VB :: ne:O
word: u :: pos: PRP :: ne:O
word: on :: pos: IN :: ne:O
word: fb :: pos: NNP :: ne:O
word: lololol :: pos: UH :: ne:O
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also just tested this against v3.6.0 (Apr 2016) of StanfordCoreNLP and the POS tagger worked fine straightaway (from .NET code).